# vagrant provision having problems with npm

Tags: linux, node.js, vagrant

I am using vagrant shell provisioning for installing node grunt and bower.

for some reason vagrant says:

> ```
> ==> default: /tmp/vagrant-shell: line 8: npm: command not found
> ==> default: /tmp/vagrant-shell: line 9: npm: command not found
> The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant
> ```

but when I log into the machine with vagrant ssh, npm command is found and i can use it just fine.

Vagrantfile:

> ```
> # -*- mode: ruby -*-
> # vi: set ft=ruby :
> $script = <<SCRIPT
> yum -y update;
> yum -y groupinstall "Development Tools";
> wget http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.11.9/node-v0.11.9.tar.gz -P /usr/src;
> tar zxf /usr/src/node-v0.11.9.tar.gz -C /usr/src;
> /usr/src/node-v0.11.9/configure;
> make -C /usr/src/node-v0.11.9/;
> make install -C /usr/src/node-v0.11.9/;
> npm install -g grunt-cli;
> npm install -g bower;
> SCRIPT
> Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
>    config.vm.box = "chef/centos-6.5"
>    config.ssh.username = 'root'
>    config.ssh.password = 'vagrant'
>  # config.vm.network "public_network"
>    config.vm.provision "shell",  
>  inline: $script
> end
> ```